# Access the elements of a list around the current element?

Tags: python, list

I am trying to figure out if it is possible to access the elements of a list around the element you are currently at. I have a list that is large (20k+ lines) and I want to find every instance of the string 'Name'. Additionally, I also want to get +/- 5 elements around each 'Name' element. So 5 lines before and 5 lines after. The code I am using is below.

```
search_string = 'Name'

with open('test.txt', 'r') as infile, open ('textOut.txt','w') as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        if search_string in line:
            outfile.writelines([line, next(infile), next(infile), 
                               next(infile), next(infile), next(infile)])
```

Getting the lines after the occurrence of 'Name' is pretty straightforward, but figuring out how to access the elements before it has me stumped. Anyone have an ideas?

Comment: I'd suggest `lines = deque(maxlen=5); lines.append(line)` and then fetch all when you find the matching line ? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

20k lines isn't *that* much, if it's ok to read all of them in a list, we can take slices around the index where a match is found, like this:

```
with open('test.txt', 'r') as infile, open('textOut.txt','w') as outfile:
    lines = [line.strip() for line in infile.readlines()]
    n = len(lines)
    for i in range(n):
        if search_string in lines[i]:
            start = max(0, i - 5)
            end = min(n, i + 6)
            outfile.writelines(lines[start:end])
```

Comment: Good solution, but you need the *preceding* 5 lines too: `lines[i - 5 : i + 5]`.

Comment: Done! The above will get the 5 lines to the left and to the right of where the match is found.

Comment: `n=len(lines)-1` or the problem will be the same ^^ and theorically, using negative indexes won't cause errors, it will simply start from the end of the iterable @ÓscarLópez

Comment: @ThomasDussaut not sure, both range and slices don't include the right end of the interval. I mean, it's `[start, end)`

Comment: Actually, there is no need for checking indices  as Python doesn't throw any error if you use negative number in slice or very big number greater than size of list. It takes how far it can take in those cases. Strange! Just verified.

Comment: @Austin but you might end up with an empty list if the indexes aren't right. I stand by my code ;)

Comment: @ÓscarLópez, your index comes from `range(n)`, so there is no possibility of getting an empty list.

Comment: @Austin if the match is in the first item, you'll get something like `lines[-5:6]`, which is empty

Comment: @ÓscarLópez, How's that empty?

Comment: @Austin an empty list. Go try it.

Comment: I agree you need index checking not to avoid errors but to get correct items from list. But this one `lines[-5:6]` does not seem empty to me. Can you share an example of this becoming empty?

Comment: Let's say there's a match at index 0, and we want to take one element before, and one element after. This is empty: `[1, 2, 3][-1:2]`, but for this question it should be `[1, 2]`

Comment: @ÓscarLópez This seems to get the job done for me, however it outputs all of the information out on one line. Is it possible to insert a line break after each line is written? .writelines() seems to take only one argument.

Comment: @MaxB then put a `write('\n')` after it, to insert a line break. If this solution worked for you, please don't forget to accept it ;)

Comment: What if the file has 500k lines? You don't need to read the whole file. Check my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the function [enumerate](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/enumerate.html) that allows you to iterate through both elements and indexes.

Example to access elements 5 indexes before and after your current element :

```py
n = len(l)
for i, x in enumerate(l):
    print(l[max(i-5, 0)])  # Prevent picking last elements of iterable by using negative indexes
    print(x)
    print(l[min(i+5, n-1)])  # Prevent overflow
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep track of the index of where in the list you currently are

So something like:

```
# Read the file into list_of_lines
index = 0
while index < len(list_of_lines):
    if list_of_lines[index] == 'Name':
        print(list_of_lines[index - 1]) # This is the previous line
        print(list_of_lines[index + 1]) # This is the next line
        # And so on...
    index += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have your lines stored in your list:

```
lines  = ['line1', 'line2', 'line3', 'line4', 'line5', 'line6', 'line7', 'line8', 'line9']
```

You could define a method returning elements grouped by n consecutives, as a generator:

```
def each_cons(iterable, n = 2):
  if n < 2: n = 1
  i, size = 0, len(iterable)
  while i < size-n+1:
    yield iterable[i:i+n]
    i += 1
```

Teen, just call the method. To show the content I'm calling list on it, but **you can iterate over it**:

```
lines_by_3_cons = each_cons(lines, 3) # or any number of lines, 5 in your case
print(list(lines_by_3_cons))

#=> [['line1', 'line2', 'line3'], ['line2', 'line3', 'line4'], ['line3', 'line4', 'line5'], ['line4', 'line5', 'line6'], ['line5', 'line6', 'line7'], ['line6', 'line7', 'line8'], ['line7', 'line8', 'line9']]
```

Answer (score 1):

I personally loved that problem. All guys here are doing it by taking the whole file into memory. I think I wrote a memory efficient code.
Here, check this out!

```
myfile = open('infile.txt')

stack_print_moments = []
expression = 'MYEXPRESSION'
neighbourhood_size = 5

def print_stack(stack):
    for line in stack:
        print(line.strip())
    print('-----')


current_stack = []
for index, line in enumerate(myfile):
    current_stack.append(line)
    if len(current_stack) > 2 * neighbourhood_size + 1:
        current_stack.pop(0)

    if expression in line:
        stack_print_moments.append(index + neighbourhood_size)

    if index in stack_print_moments:
        print_stack(current_stack)

last_index = index

for index in range(last_index, last_index + neighbourhood_size + 1):
    if index in stack_print_moments:
        print_stack(current_stack)
    current_stack.pop(0)
```

More advanced code is here: [Github link](https://gist.github.com/nejdetckenobi/e8493d40f7d3d12977bdb87881258c56)